# Skip first rows when writing csv (pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

In my python script I am reading a csv file via

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=';', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", skiprows=2, skipfooter=1, engine='python')
```

I am the skipping the first two rows in the csv file because they are just discriptions I don't need.

After importing, I am filtering and separating the data. **I want to write the data back to csv files while having the same format as before (first two rows either empty or the description as before the import)**. How can I do that?

Currently I am using

```
df.to_csv('output.csv'), sep=';', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Is there something like a parameter "skiprows" for exporting? I can't find one in the [api documentation for .to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: Could you not write your description first and then append to the file? Or just write 2 new lines and then append? There isn't a built in api in `pandas` for this

Comment: Maybe you are right. I see you can use `mode='a'` for appending when writing csv. So I just need to create a csv file with two empty rows before exporting.

Comment: Appending to a pre-existing file is trivial, there isn't a method built in `pandas` to do this using `to_csv`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is write DataFrame with `NaN`s first and then append original `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan] * 2})
df1.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", mode='a')
```

Or same original header to `df1` and this write first, only necessary no value `|` in header data:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep='|', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", nrows=2, names=['tmp'])

df1.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", mode='a')
```

Comment: Perfect, first solution works for me. I will switch to the second one if i really need the description later. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer @jezrael, just wanted to know if we have a way to `skip first row` alone in .to_csv() ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the header from your original file and write to your new file. Then you append your dataframe by setting mode to 'a'

```
with open("my_csv.csv") as f:
    header =''
    for line in range(0,header_length_in_lines):
        header +=f.readline()

with open('my_new_csv.csv','w+') as f:
    f.write(header)
df.to_csv('my_new_csv.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

Comment: I want to export a dataframe (500 rows,2 coulmns) from python to a csv file.

However, I need to ensure that 1st 20 rows has some text/strings written and then the dataframe should should start from 21st row onwards.

Can somebody please let me know how do we do this?