# How to write to CSV starting at row x?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to do the opposite of :

```
read_csv(file, skiprows = 2)
```

Like :

```
df.to_csv(file, skiprows = 30)
```

A simple `df.to_csv` will print all data starting from row 1. How to start printing at row 30? I want to print starting at row 30 into CSV.

Comment: Try this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499948/skip-first-rows-when-writing-csv-pandas-dataframe-to-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this would be :

```
df.to_excel(writer,index=True,header=True,sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow=25,startcol=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just select the remainder of the dataframe after the first 30 rows:

```
df.iloc[30:].to_csv(file)
```

Comment: Hi @DYZ, that would not be the exact answer I'm looking for. What I would need is to print on the excel sheet on row 30. Not cut the data starting from row 30 and print on row 1.

Comment: This is what you asked for. There is no way to "start printing on Excel sheet on row 30." The best you can do is to add 30 empty rows at the top of the dataframe.