# How to combine text and pandas dataframe in 1 CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to pandas and wondering if it is possible to combine text and pandas dataframe in a single csv file.

I can write the dataframe to a csv file without problem, but I would like to put some description above the dataframe to describe when did I collect the data.
Please see the attachment about what I would like to achieve.

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip first rows when writing csv (pandas.DataFrame.to\_csv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499948/skip-first-rows-when-writing-csv-pandas-dataframe-to-csv)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for David's post.
I think the "encoding='ISO-8859-1' is the key.
What I did is put the description in the csv file first, run the script again, it added the dataframe underneath the description.
Here is the code

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dateDir, orient='index').to_csv('test.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1',mode='a')

Answer (score 0):

You really answered you own question

1. get CSV into string
2. use an f-string to modify it
3. save it as CSV

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame([[i for i in range(0,10)] for j in range(0,10)], columns=[chr(97+i) for i in range(0,10)])
fname = "file.csv"
data = df.to_csv(index=False)
data = f'''Date of month: {datetime.now().month}
From Date: {str(datetime(2020,7,1))}
To Date: {str(datetime(2020,7,30))}


{data}'''
with open(fname, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
print(data)
```

**output**

```
Date of month: 7
From Date: 2020-07-01 00:00:00
To Date: 2020-07-30 00:00:00


a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```